# d3.js brush with multiline chart

Tags: d3.js, brush

I'm making a multi-line chart and using a brush to select time periods. It's broadly based on Mike Bostock's example at http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1667367

My chart is at http://lowercasen.com/dev/d3/general/piezobrush.html

My problem is in selecting the multiple lines in my 'focus' area to apply the brush to. I've nested the data based on a key, so the data is within a function. Because the function that calls my brush is outside that function, it can't access the data and I'm getting a TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'data.length')

Here's the code that nests the data:

```
     dataNest.forEach(function(d, i) {

       focus.append("path")
           .attr("class", "line")
                 .attr("id", d.key.replace(/\s+/g, ''))  //the replace stuff is getting rid of spaces
                 .attr("d", levelFocus(d.values)); 

       context.append("path")
            .attr("class", "line")
                 .attr("id", d.key.replace(/\s+/g, ''))  //the replace stuff is getting rid of spaces
                 .attr("d", levelContext(d.values));
```

and at the bottom I have the function for the brush:

```
     function brushed() {
       xFocus.domain(brush.empty() ? xContext.domain() : brush.extent());
       focus.selectAll(".line").attr("d", levelFocus(d.values));
       focus.select(".x.axis").call(xAxisFocus);
     }
```

It works fine for the x axis (if I comment out the line where I'm trying to select the lines) but I don't know how to select the lines correctly.

Apologies for any garbled syntax or confusing language, my coding skills are basic at best.

Any help is greatly appreciated, I've searched for hours for a solution.

Here's the full code as requested by Lars

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <title>Multiline with brush</title>
    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.js"></script>
    <script src="d3/tooltip.js"></script>
        <link href="styles/evidentlySoCharts.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1">   

    <style>

    svg {
      font: 10px sans-serif;
    }

    path { 
        stroke-width: 1;
        fill: none;
    }

    #Stream1, #Nebo1D {
        stroke: #009390;
    }

    #Stream1Legend, #Nebo1DLegend {
        fill: #009390;
    }

    #Stream2, #Nebo2D {
        stroke: #8dc63f;
    }

    #Stream2Legend, #Nebo2DLegend {
        fill: #8dc63f;
    }

    #Stream3, #Nebo1S {
        stroke: #132d46;
    }

    #Stream3Legend, #Nebo1SLegend {
        fill: #132d46;
    }

    #Stream4, #Nebo2S {
        stroke: #aaa813;
    }

    #Stream4Legend, #Nebo2SLegend {
        fill: #aaa813;
    }

    #Stream5, #Nebo3 {
        stroke: #619dd4;
    }

    #Stream5Legend, #Nebo3Legend {
        fill: #619dd4;
    }

    .pn1d, .pn2d {
      fill: none;
      clip-path: url(#clip);
    }

    .pn1d {
      stroke: #009390;
    }

    .pn2d {
      stroke: #1b4164;
    }

    .axis path,
    .axis line {
      fill: none;
      stroke: #000;
      stroke-width: 1px;
      shape-rendering: crispEdges;
    }

    .brush .extent {
      stroke: #fff;
      fill-opacity: .125;
      shape-rendering: crispEdges;
    }

    </style>
        </head>



    <body>
    <script>

    var marginFocus = {top: 10, right: 10, bottom: 250, left: 40},
        marginContext = {top: 430, right: 10, bottom: 170, left: 40},
        width = 960 - marginFocus.left - marginFocus.right,
        heightFocus = 650 - marginFocus.top - marginFocus.bottom,
        heightContext = 650 - marginContext.top - marginContext.bottom;
        legendOffset = 550;

    var parseDate = d3.time.format("%d/%m/%y %H:%M").parse;

    var xFocus = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]),
        xContext = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]),
        yFocus = d3.scale.linear().range([heightFocus, 0]),
        yContext = d3.scale.linear().range([heightContext, 0]);

    var xAxisFocus = d3.svg.axis().scale(xFocus).orient("bottom"),
        xAxisContext = d3.svg.axis().scale(xContext).orient("bottom"),
        yAxisFocus = d3.svg.axis().scale(yFocus).orient("left");

    var levelFocus = d3.svg.line()
        .interpolate("linear")
        .x(function(d) { return xFocus(d.date); })
        .y(function(d) { return yFocus(d.level); });


    var levelContext = d3.svg.line()
        .interpolate("linear")
        .x(function(d) { return xContext(d.date); })
        .y(function(d) { return yContext(d.level); });

    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + marginFocus.left + marginFocus.right)
        .attr("height", heightFocus + marginFocus.top + marginFocus.bottom);

    svg.append("defs").append("clipPath")
        .attr("id", "clip")
      .append("rect")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", heightFocus);

    var focus = svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "focus")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + marginFocus.left + "," + marginFocus.top + ")");

    var context = svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "context")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + marginContext.left + "," + marginContext.top + ")");

    d3.csv("data/PiezoNeboNestSimple.csv", function(error, data) {
        data.forEach(function(d) {
        d.date = parseDate(d.date);
        d.level = +d.level;
        });

      xFocus.domain(d3.extent(data.map(function(d) { return d.date; })));
      yFocus.domain([d3.min(data.map(function(d) { return d.level; })) -2,0]);
      xContext.domain(xFocus.domain());
      yContext.domain(yFocus.domain());

        // Nest the entries by piezo
        var dataNest = d3.nest()
            .key(function(d) {return d.piezo;})
            .entries(data);

        legendSpace = width/dataNest.length; // spacing for legend // ******

    var brush = d3.svg.brush()
        .x(xContext)
        .on("brush", brushed);


    focus.selectAll("g").data(dataNest)
        .enter()
        .append("g")
        .attr("class", "line")
        .attr("id", function(d) { return d.key.replace(/\s+/g, '') })  //the replace stuff is getting rid of spaces
        .append("path")
        .attr("d", function(d) { return levelFocus(d.values); });    

    context.selectAll("g").data(dataNest)
        .enter()
        .append("g")
        .attr("class", "line")
        .attr("id", function(d) { return d.key.replace(/\s+/g, '') })  //the replace stuff is getting rid of spaces
        .append("path")
        .attr("d", function(d) { return levelContext(d.values); });    


      focus.append("g")
          .attr("class", "x axis")
          .attr("transform", "translate(0," + heightFocus + ")")
          .call(xAxisFocus);

      focus.append("g")
          .attr("class", "y axis")
          .call(yAxisFocus);

      context.append("g")
          .attr("class", "x axis")
          .attr("transform", "translate(0," + heightContext + ")")
          .call(xAxisContext);

      context.append("g")
          .attr("class", "x brush")
          .call(brush)
        .selectAll("rect")
          .attr("y", -6)
          .attr("height", heightContext + 7);

    function brushed() {
      xFocus.domain(brush.empty() ? xContext.domain() : brush.extent());
      focus.selectAll(".line").attr("d", levelFocus(dataNest.values));
      focus.select(".x.axis").call(xAxisFocus);
    }

    });


    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Could you define the `brushed` function in the same scope as `data`?

Comment: Lars, I've tried to in my inexpert way, but without success. I'm pretty sure they need to end up in the same scope somehow but my skills are lacking. 

Mind you, other examples (with a single line or area rather than my multiple ones) define it outside the data scope. Still, I think you're on the right track. Are you able to give me an idea of how to do that?

Comment: @LarsKotthoff I've updated it to have the brushed function in the same scope as data, but still with no joy. The problem is in this line
'focus.selectAll(".line").attr("d", levelFocus(d.values));'
and the error I'm getting is that it can't find the variable d. Basically, I don't know how to reference the lines that I've added to the chart.

Comment: Referencing the data won't work in your case because you're not binding the data to the elements. For multiple lines, use nested selections instead of a loop as in [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3884955).

Comment: Hi Lars. I can see that that would solve the problem, but I don't know how to go about it. Are you able to point me to an example of how this is done? 

Apologies for being a bit needy, my coding skills are poor. Your time and help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I would start from the example that I've linked to. Adapting this to your data shouldn't be too difficult. Once that's done, you can add the context chart (which is the same thing as the main chart really). For the brush you should be able to reuse your existing code almost as-is.

Comment: Hi Lars. Thanks for your continued help. I don't think I've explained the structure of my data well enough. Each entry has the name of a 'piezo' (a measurement site), the date and a value. It needs to be nested by the key 'piezo' because it contains all streams in the one data set. The client adds to it in this format. A big problem is that the dates are not the same for each piezo – one of them might have a reading taken at a time when none of the others do. The nesting is working fine, but I can't seem to extract the data for just one stream so that I can visualise it.

Comment: Here's a link to my data so that you can see its structure. Note that new readings for each piezo will be added to the bottom. [link to data](http://lowercasen.com/dev/d3/general/data/PiezoNeboNestSimple.csv)

Comment: I should add that I have tried adapting the link you provided to my data (for way too long) and searched for relevant examples online (for way too long), but I can't find any way to isolate each stream. I don't just expect you to do it for me, but I've really hit a roadblock and I need a pointer to help me muddle through. Thanks again.

Comment: Ok, so after the nesting you would do something like `svg.selectAll("g").data(nestedData).append("g").append("path").attr("d", function(d) { return lineGenerator(d.values); })`. You wouldn't even need nested selections in this case.

Comment: Thanks Lars, I'm getting close. That gives me one line, for the data associated with the first key, in the 'focus' area and a second for the data associated with the second key in the 'context' area, but nothing more. If I could just refer to them by their key values I could add each of them to both areas (and style them separately etc.).

Comment: Sorry, forgot a `.enter()` there. Should be `svg.selectAll("g").data(nestedData).append("g").enter().append("path").attr("d", function(d) { return lineGenerator(d.values); })`.

Comment: @Lars OK, I've been able to visualise all of the nested data without a loop, but I'm back to my original problem of not being able to apply the brush. I have the 'brushed' function in the same scope as the data but it can't seem to access the data in the same way. If I use `d` it can't find the variable, if I use `dataNest` it returns `TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'data.length')`. Thanks for your continued patience with this.

Comment: Where are you evaluating `data.length`? Should that be `dataNest.length`?

Comment: To be honest, I don't know. The brushed function only refers to dataNest: `function brushed() {
  xFocus.domain(brush.empty() ? xContext.domain() : brush.extent());
  focus.selectAll(".line").attr("d", levelFocus(dataNest.values));
  focus.select(".x.axis").call(xAxisFocus);
}
` while the levelFocus function just uses d: `var levelFocus = d3.svg.line()
    .interpolate("linear")
    .x(function(d) { return xFocus(d.date); })
    .y(function(d) { return yFocus(d.level); });
`. I've tried putting the lineFocus function in the same scope and changing it to `xFocus(dataNest.date)` without success.

Comment: The console only refers to a line in d3.v3.js, not my code.

Comment: Could you put the complete code up somewhere please?

Comment: Many apologies, I had assumed you were looking at the code from my original example. I'm new to posting on SO, so I'm a bit ignorant of the protocols. If you need to check the data it's [available here.](http://lowercasen.com/dev/d3/general/data/PiezoNeboNestSimple.csv)

Comment: Ok, but you've modified the code that you've posted here originally, yes? I need to see exactly what you're running to get the error you describe.

Comment: I've modified the code according to your suggestions. So it's no longer looping through the keys but instead using nested selections and the brush function is now in the same scope as the data. The code has been updated but the problem is still the same one I described in the initial question. I've been working on the live html page, so if you look at the link from the original post it'll be the one that is giving me the issue I describe. Let me know if I didn't explain that properly.

Comment: It should be `levelFocus(d.values)` and not `levelFocus(dataNest.values)` inside the `brushed` function, shouldn't it?

Comment: If I use levelFocus(d.values) I get `ReferenceError: Can't find variable: d`. I've just changed it to this to demonstrate. I agree that it should be correct, but I don't know why it can't find d – it's in the same scope.

Comment: You need to wrap this in `function(d) { return levelFocus(d); })`. Basically the same thing you're using to set `d` initially.

Comment: That makes perfect sense, but it's still not working. I've tried it with `function(d) { return levelFocus(d); })`, with `function(d) { return levelFocus(d.values); })` and by selecting each line individually by their id, but they all have the same result: no brushing (except on the x axis) and no console error. It's like that line is being ignored. Thanks again for your help, I know it's frustrating with the time difference.

Comment: You were selecting and updating the `g` elements, not the `path` elements: http://plnkr.co/edit/i0Y7573B8SVlTjsHZ317?p=preview

Comment: That's extremely brilliant. Thanks heaps for your patience and knowledge. How do we go about making this the correct answer? I see that we're not really meant to be doing this all in comments.

Comment: I'll add an answer with the two things that I think it boils down to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It mostly boils down to two things as far as I can see. First, the elements you're selecting to be updated are the `g` and not the `path` elements and second, you need to reference the data bound to the elements in order to set `d`. Both are easily fixed and the `brushed` function looks something like this.

```
function brushed() {
   xFocus.domain(brush.empty() ? xContext.domain() : brush.extent());
   focus.selectAll("path").attr("d", function(d) { return levelFocus(d.values); });
   focus.select(".x.axis").call(xAxisFocus);
}
```

Complete demo [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/i0Y7573B8SVlTjsHZ317?p=preview). Note that some bits are still missing, in particular the clip path to restrict the lines to the chart area. This can be copied and pasted directly from the example you've referenced though.